# Objective-C, ARC: Is it correct to use __weak arguments?

Tags: objective-c, arguments, automatic-ref-counting, weak-references

Here's a little example of using weak arguments:

```
@interface MYTestObject : NSObject

@end

@implementation MYTestObject {
   void(^_block)(void);
}

- (void)dealloc {
   NSLog(@"DEALLOC!");
}

- (id)init {
   if (self = [super init]) {
      [self doSomethingWithObject:self];
   }
   return self;
}

- (void)doSomethingWithObject:(id __weak /* <- weak argument! */)obj {
   _block = ^{
      NSLog(@"%p", obj);
   };
}

@end
```

And it works: `-dealloc` is called!
Also, if you remove `__weak` you'll get a retain-cycle and it's absolutely correct.

Wonder, if that's just a side-effect and it's completely unsafe to use weak arguments? Or is it a specified behavior and I'm just a bad google-user?

Comment: weak ref means no retaining, so i think it's proper behaviour

Comment: Yes, You're right, but I can't find a specification to be sure.

Comment: I mean a spec about arguments, not ivars, properties, etc.

Comment: @Rob: As far as I know, even with ARC you have to copy a block in some situations.

Answer (score 5):

Two observations:

1. I'd be inclined to make a local `__weak` reference within `doSomethingWithObject`, rather than make it a `__weak` argument as illustrated in [Avoid Strong Reference Cycles when Capturing `self`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH8-SW16).

   I don't think that it is, as you asked, "completely unsafe to use weak arguments." But if nothing else, it's the more common pattern to have a local `__weak` variable and strikes me as more appropriate as an implementation detail of `doSomethingWithObject` rather than part of the method's public interface.
2. I'd also make `block` a property with the `copy` memory qualifier. As [the docs say](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH8-SW12)

   > You should specify `copy` as the property attribute, because a block needs to be copied to keep track of its captured state outside of the original scope. This isn’t something you need to worry about when using Automatic Reference Counting, as it will happen automatically, but it's best practice for the property attribute to show the resultant behavior.

Thus:

```
@interface MYTestObject : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) void(^block)(void);
@end

@implementation MYTestObject

- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"DEALLOC!");
}

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        [self doSomethingWithObject:self];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)doSomethingWithObject:(MYTestObject *)obj { 
    
    typeof(obj) __weak weakObj = obj;
    
    self.block = ^{
        NSLog(@"%p", weakObj);
    };
}

@end
```

Comment: thanks, @Rob! i know about alternative solutions, but my question is from the category of "what if?" questions =)

Comment: @i_am_mushroom Understood. The answer is that you _can_, but that you probably _should not._ It's technically fine, but in my opinion not great stylistically (hence my suggestion of a preferred pattern).

Comment: you know, i asked some co-workers about subj and they were quite scared =) ...so may be it's not ok even if it's a proven technique. Anyway i also sent the question to [Clang Front End Users List](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/mailman/listinfo/cfe-users).